# See photos in grandchild features full size in attribute table inn QGIS

Tags: qgis, attribute-table, photos

I have a project where the features (some plants) have a child feature 'observations', which have their own child features, photos.  If I look at a specific plant in the attribute table, I get a very small thumbnail of a grandchild photo, as at the bottom of this screen cap [image]

I would expect to be able to do something such as right-click on the thumbnail and get an RMB menu with an option such as 'view photo', but of course that doesn't work.  Is there someway to do this easily?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming the width and height are set to auto-resize, as in the image below

[image]

You need to expand the view of the table and it will auto-resize.

[image]

To see a bigger size than the limit of the attribute table in the dock mode, you can do the following:

1. Detach the attribute table by clicking on the `Dock attribute table` button

[image]

2. Maximize the window

[image]

It covers the full screen:

[image]

Comment: Thanks! This is helpful! Clicking on the little arrows so that they point to the right instead of down, and then going full-screen also helps get a bigger size, but best would be a quick way to actually open the image with an app or choice, for editing, saving a copy to some other location, etc etc.